# HTML form validation based on bean validation in a JAX-RS 2.0 application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, bean-validation

We know JAX-RS made it easy to map form input values directly to server bean properties or method parameters.

Now JAX-RS 2.0 provides a way to validate the server side values using bean validation, that is really amazing.

But how could we present useful validation information in the front end (to the user who submits the HTTP form) in an Ajax way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible approach is the following. Create ErrorEntity class, something like

```
@XmlRootEntity
public class ErrorEntity{
  private String errorCode;
  private String description;

  //getters, setter, constructors

}
```

then, in case of error throw:

```
int statusCode = 500;
ErrorEntity ee = new ErrorEntity("SYSTEM", "Cannot connect to database, etc.");
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(statusCode).entity(ee).build());
```

Obviously use proper HTTP error code (400 for malformed content, 404 for missing data, etc.).

In the AJAX application if you get something different then 200, 204 or 302 expect that you should obtain JSON or XML with ErrorEntity content.

The simplest solution is to simply return String as a entity with some error information + HTTP status code.

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(500).entity("Cannot connect to DB, ...").build());
```